# Запретить изменение размера окна, поменять заголовок и вставить иконку в окне приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Я уже создал приложение, используя *Qt Designer*, а сейчас понял что мне необходимо пофиксить некоторые моменты, но возвращаться и изменять параметры непосредственно в *Qt Designer* и заново конвертировать желания нет.

Помогите решить вопросы:

1. Запретить растягивание формы, чтобы была фиксация всегда той формы, что имеется.
2. Изменить заголовок с "Form" на другой и добавить к нему `Icon` (например, классический Qt).

И еще есть один неприятный момент. Программа может сама закрыться, если встретила ошибку. Например, при нажатии на кнопку с `lineEdit` должна считываться информация и обрабатываться, но если, допустим, пользователь не указал ничего и нажал на кнопку, то она мгновенно закрывается.

Как сделать так, чтобы программа не закрылась пока не нажмешь на красный крестик? Как прописать функцию ошибки? Подскажите как это прописать непосредственно в коде. Спасибо заранее.

Пример кода:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from testy import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(199, 240)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Сложить"))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_a_b)        

    def add_a_b(self):
        a = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        b = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str(a + b))              # - (a + b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ну второе это метод `setWIndowTitle()` насколько я помню, а первое, вроде `resizable()`, или `isresizable()`, посмотрите в поиске

Comment: В существующем виде вопрос не соответствует правилам. Заголовок вопроса, должен коротко передавать его суть. В данном случае, это нелегко потому, что в одном вопросе сразу много всего намешано. Разделите и создайте несколько конкретных вопросов.

Comment: Предоставьте свой пример, который демонстрирует то что вы описали.

Comment: У меня большой код. Можно на этом примере показать.[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128785/Помогите-разобраться-в-pyqt5-как-правильно-преобразовать-lineedit-к-типу-int-и-д]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, **всегда предоставляйте минимальный пример** !!!

Смотрите комментарии по тексту примера.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from testy import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(199, 240)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Сложить"))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # запретить растягивание формы, чтоб была фиксация всегда той формы,что имеется
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())                                # <<<-----<

        # изменить заголовок с "Form" на другой
        self.setWindowTitle("другой заголовок")                       # <<<-----<

        # добавить к нему Icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))                     # <<<-----<

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_a_b)        

    def add_a_b(self):

        # если , допустим, пользователь не указал ничего и нажал на кнопку, то она мгновенно закрывается.
        if self.lineEdit.text() and self.lineEdit_2.text():           # <<<-----<
            a = int(self.lineEdit.text())
            b = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            self.lineEdit_3.setText(str(a + b))    
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните поля ввода!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы лучший) спасибо огромное!!